# How to use another computed property inside mounted or created hooks?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is my my code?

```
computed: {
    posts() {
        return this.$store.getters['posts/postsByUser']
    },
    
    loggedIn() {
        return this.$store.getters['auth/check'];
    },
    user() {
        return this.$store.getters['auth/user']
    }
},
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('posts/fetchPostsByUser', this.user.id)
}
```

Please tell me if you need more clearance

Comment: `this.user.id` is how you reference it

Comment: yes it is a typo mistake

Comment: What's the issue? Is your `dispatch` not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: when dispatching, this.user.id is undefined. it means it not loaded ye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this computed property (user) which is available on the Vue component instance

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('posts/fetchPostsByUser', this.user.id)
}
```

Comment: Maybe your computed properties are ready after the created hook has finished. It's a race condition. try to add the created code in this.$nextTick()

Comment: can you explain it how?